# What is the AT&T syntax postfix for opcodes?

Tags: macos, assembly, 64-bit, freebsd, att

*NOTE: I'm using a BSD based system so if I remember correctly this means args for called subroutines/functions are pushed onto the stack not placed in registers*

I've been trying out assembly and I wanted to try my simple kernel-exit program:

```
.globl _start

_start:
    movl $0x20, %eax
    pushl %eax
    movl $0x1, %eax
    subl $0x4, %esp
    int $0x80
```

in 64 bit assembly.

I remember reading that a large difference is the registers are now renamed `r` prefixed instead of the 32 bit standard of an `e` prefix.

But what is the new postfix for 64 bit opcodes, if `l` already means long for 32 bits?

Out of curiosity why is it an `r` prefix for the new registers?

Also if there are any good resources where further information could be found. Or tutorials, tutorials are always fun.

Comment: The calling convention is different for 64 bit applications than 32-bit applications, so you will use registers, not the stack. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2538212/458390) for the details. The 64-bit postfix is `q` for quadword. The `r` prefix is probably because AMD created the 64-bit extensions first, so Intel didn't have a chance to add some other letter which meant "extended".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The postfix is `q` for *qword*, and `r` supposedly stands for *register*. [Here's](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/assembly.html) an introduction in AT&T syntax.

Comment: Any idea why `l` is not `d` for dword? Or is it just remnants of GAS being made for C compilation? Come to think of it why doesn't C use `word` and `dword` instead of `short` and `long` respectively?

Comment: As to the design decisions that went into AT&T syntax, I can only speculate that it was strongly tied to C. And as to the design decisions that went into C, I couldn't say :P